# Tool to generate technical documentation website from markdown

Tags: r-markdown, markdown, documentation

I'm looking for a tool to generate a *static* website to host some internal documentation, like dev tips, tools we use, a few simple tutorials etc.. The idea being to share it among the team, rather informally.

I'm sure there are many tools out there, and it's actually pretty overwhelming to try and choose one. `rmarkdown` / `blogdown` look pretty cool but I had never heard of it before. [Github Markdown Render](https://github.com/magnetikonline/github-markdown-render) seems interesting (but not static), there are certainly hundreds of tools for blogs, and lots to generate sites from code (Sphinx, Doxygen).

More specific requirement :

- As simple as possible, ideally creating the website files in one command line. We don't need a full blown WordPress setup.
- Nice rendering, especially for code. I love Github rendering for ex.
- Possibility to navigate between files.
- Well supported / big community.
- If possible, customizable for looks and a to give more control on layout etc.. Not a priority though.
- General enough so that I can change tool if someday I decide I want finer control.

Do you guys have any recommendations?

PS : I chose markdown because it seems to be the most common and I already know / use it, but I'm open to rest or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's interested, I landed on using `Hugo` with [hugo-geekdoc](https://github.com/thegeeklab/hugo-geekdoc)

- Looks great out of the box
- Really easy to setup / build / deploy
- Customizable at will (though I try not to loose too much time doing so)

[image: screenshot]

Obviously it's a personal choice, and other solutions like `docsify` as @cyrus mentioned, or even the `github wiki` could also fit.

Answer (score 1):

[docsify](https://github.com/docsifyjs/docsify) might meet your needs.

[image: dosify]

[image: docsify-themeable]

> As simple as possible, ideally creating the website files in one command line.

A docsify site is created in one command.

```sh
docsify init ./docs
```

> Possibility to navigate between files.

There is a sidebar to navigate between files.

> Well supported / big community.

It's a 17.3k project. There are 160 contributors now(April 16, 2021).

> Nice rendering, especially for code.
>
> If possible, customizable for looks and a to give more control on layout.

It's customizable. You can find websites created by docsify and themes for docsify on [Awesome Docsify](https://github.com/docsifyjs/awesome-docsify).

> General enough so that I can change tool if someday I decide I want finer control.

Don't worry. Many tools support Markdown. You can change the tool whenever you want.

Comment: Wow it looks really cool thanks! However I'd rather have a static website because it is more portable and I can access the doc locally without running a server. I'll have a look though.

Comment: You can run the website locally via `docsify serve docs`. Please read the manual for more infomation.

Comment: Yes I've seen that but it's not exactly a static server, in fact it seems that it is made on purpose to generate the HTML dynamically, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think blogdown would be even better, but I don't need all the R embedding stuff